# Purpose of Association mapping with Hibernate in all entities if schema has already been defined in db manually

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have created a SQL DB with association mapping or relationships and constraints for all tables. Now i mapping them to my java classes with JPA annotations. Is it mandatory to Map relationship between each entity even if foreign key constraints have been defined in tables. Will this result in error or is there a strong purpose behind this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not required to map assocations but it greatly simplifies the usage in HQL queries as you can simply join the well defined assocations instead of doing explicit joins of entities with an explicit ON clause.